# Laravel - Name instead of ID

Tags: laravel

Somehow I can't trace what is wrong with my codes. I'm trying to display a typ_name instead of id, so I defined the following relationship in both type and infrastructure models but I can't able to display the name.

Models codes shown below

type.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * Class type
 * @package App\Models
 * @version January 16, 2020, 4:01 am UTC
 *
 * @property string typ_name
 */
class type extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'types';


    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



    public $fillable = [
        'typ_name'
    ];

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('infrastructure');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'typ_name' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'typ_name' => 'required'
    ];


}
```

infrastructure.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * Class infrastructure
 * @package App\Models
 * @version January 23, 2020, 1:44 am UTC
 *
 * @property string inf_name
 * @property integer inf_height
 * @property integer inf_width
 * @property integer typ_id
 * @property integer island_id
 * @property integer engnr_id
 * @property integer designer_id
 * @property integer foreman_id
 * @property string start_date
 * @property string cmplt_date
 * @property string inf_lifspan
 * @property string inf_file
 * @property integer inf_lat
 * @property integer inf_long
 * @property string inf_comment
 */
class infrastructure extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'infrastructures';


    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



    public $fillable = [
        'inf_name',
        'inf_height',
        'inf_width',
        'inf_length',
        'typ_id',
        'island_id',
        'engnr_id',
        'designer_id',
        'foreman_id',
        'start_date',
        'cmplt_date',
        'inf_lifspan',
        'inf_file',
        'inf_lat',
        'inf_long',
        'inf_comment'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the type record associated with the Infrastructure.
     */
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('type', 'typ_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'inf_name' => 'string',
        'inf_height' => 'integer',
        'inf_width' => 'integer',
        'inf_length' => 'integer',
        'typ_id' => 'integer',
        'island_id' => 'integer',
        'engnr_id' => 'integer',
        'designer_id' => 'integer',
        'foreman_id' => 'integer',
        'start_date' => 'date',
        'cmplt_date' => 'date',
        'inf_lifspan' => 'date',
        'inf_lat' => 'double',
        'inf_long' => 'double',
        'inf_comment' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'inf_name' => 'required',
        'inf_height' => 'required',
        'inf_width' => 'required',
        'inf_length' => 'required',
        'typ_id' => 'required',
        'island_id' => 'required',
        'engnr_id' => 'required',
        'designer_id' => 'required',
        'foreman_id' => 'required',
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'cmplt_date' => 'required',
        'inf_lifspan' => 'required',
        'inf_file' => 'required',
        'inf_lat' => 'required',
        'inf_long' => 'required',
        'inf_comment' => 'required'
    ];


}
```

infrastructureController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $infrastructure = $this->infrastructureRepository->find($id);

    if (empty($infrastructure)) {
        Flash::error('Infrastructure not found');

        return redirect(route('infrastructures.index'));
    }



    return view('infrastructures.show')->with('infrastructure', $infrastructure);
}
```

In my blade.php

```
<!-- Typ Id Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('typ_id', 'Type:') !!}
    {{ $infrastructure->type->typ_name }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you defined your relation wrong in your `infrastructure.php`.

Should be

```php
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(type::class, 'typ_id');
}
```

`typ_id` being your foreign key in your `infrastructures` (?) table

Also, don't forget to adjust your type.php

```php
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(infrastructure::class);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have changed that but still having problems too.
Class 'type' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\IDS\resources\views\infrastructures\show_fields.blade.php)

Comment: Could you post these files completely? We have to know the namespace.

Comment: I have edited my post so you should be able to see the complete scripts now for both models.

Comment: @TekitaaMautaake, edited my answer to reflect your changed question. If that will work, you will have to change type class accordingly